# Not well-formed error on cgi

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cgi

I am trying to send data from Ajax to a python script, however I am getting a `not well-formed` error in the console. Could you guys have a look please?

**jQuery / Ajax**

```
    function send_data() {
        console.log("Sending Data")
        var data = {
            id: '20',
            action: 'Test'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "./cgi-bin/datahandler.py",
            data: data, 
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
           },
        });
```

**Python script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb

cgitb.enable()

data = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "The id data is: " + data["id"].value
print "<br />"
print "The action data is: " + data["action"].value
print "<br />"
print data
```

**Error**

Not well-formed refers to the first line in the python script `#!/usr/bin/python`. If I remove the line I get a syntax error on the next.

[image: Error]

Solution
Added .py extention to `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py`
other problems solved with the help of [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1751674.html)

Comment: Try removing `dataType: "json",` and 
            `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: Try a space between shebang and executable. And check whether the file has a BOM.